# Writing output in separate folders for each file in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to read in all files in a folder in R, and the write the outputs for all of them in a separate folder (foldername = inputfilename). I don't think the way I am defining tmp is correct now.

```
print("Starting the script...")
wd = "/home/something/data/"
setwd(wd)
file_list <- list.files()

for (file in file_list){

  tmp <- cbind(wd, "/../")
  sink(tmp, append=TRUE, split=FALSE)

  ccf(data$pred_z,data$hr_z)

}
```

Secondly, I also need the ccf graph output saved as pdf or png. It's not a plot I guess, so I am not sure how to do this. Many thanks!

Comment: If you want to concatenate different strings into a single path, you could use `paste`: `tmp <- paste("/../",wd,sep = "")`. Otherwise I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Agreed - `cbind` is *not* what you want to be using for string concatenation. Use `paste`, `paste0`, or `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks, tmp <- paste(wd, "../results",  sep="") works. Any idea for the graph output of ccf?

Comment: Ok, got that as well with   dev.copy(png,filename)
  dev.off()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of graphics can be saved in a file with:

```
 dev.copy(png,filename) dev.off()
```

The output of the screen can be saved in a text file like this:

```
 wd = "/home/something/data/"
 tmp <- paste(wd, "../otherdir/file.txt", sep="")
 sink(tmp, append=TRUE, split=FALSE)
```

The redirect to the screen again (you'll want to do this before changing the previous sink to another file, otherwise your sink stack will get full):

```
sink()
```